# Apply different function in multiple columns after groupby

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

I'm struggling to apply `head(1)` to a column, aggregation to another column, and logical expression to another column, after groupby.

I have a dataframe `df` like this:

```
df <- data.frame(ref = c(rep("123", 3), rep("456", 3), rep("789", 4)),
                 carrier = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "E", "F", "A"), 
                 distance = c(20, 10, 40, 20, 90, 30, 20, 20, 30, 70),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


>df
ref    carrier    distance
123          A          20
123          A          10
123          B          40
456          C          20
456          C          90
456          C          30
789          D          20
789          E          20
789          F          30
789          A          70
```

I want to do these things below.

1. group by `ref`
2. mutate a column `first_carrier` where the first value of the `carrier` column of each group is returned
3. mutate a column `agg_distance` where the aggregated value of `distance` column in each group is returned
4. mutate a column `plus_100` where TRUE is returned if the `agg_distance` is greater than 350, FALSE is smaller than 100.

So the result should look like this.

```
ref  first_carrier  agg_distance  plus_100
123              A            70     FALSE
456              C           140      TRUE  
789              D           140      TRUE
```

My attempt:

```
  df_new <- df %>%
    group_by(ref) %>%
    mutate("agg_distance" = summarise(sum(distance)) %>%
    mutate("plus_100" = ifelse(agg_distance >= 100, T, F))
```

But I'm just not sure how to take the first carrier in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `data.table` verion made from @LAP input:

**Please hand LAP the likes**

```
df<-
setDT(df)[,.(first_carrier = carrier[1],
             agg_distance  = sum(distance)),by="ref"][,plus_100 := ifelse(agg_distance >= 100, T, F)]

#> df
#   ref first_carrier agg_distance plus_100
#1: 123             A           70    FALSE
#2: 456             C          140     TRUE
#3: 789             D          140     TRUE
```

Comment: Nice, +1! Did you try my `dplyr` code, as it does not seem to work for the OP?

Comment: I liked LAP's idea but didn't work for some weird reason. Yours is inspired by his and worked for me perfectly. I wanted to give both of you guys the best answer but yours directly solved my problem so i chose yours :) thank you very much for both of you guys!

Comment: have you tried to use @LAP code like that `dplyr::summarise(...` thats means just adding the `dplyr::` infront?

Comment: Probably its due to masking with `plyr`?

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it on your own. `summarise` is used without `mutate`. To get the first carrier, just call on the first row of the `carrier` column after grouping.

```
library(dplyr)

df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(ref) %>%
  summarise(first_carrier = carrier[1],
            agg_distance = sum(distance),
            plus_100 = ifelse(agg_distance >= 100, T, F))

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    ref first_carrier agg_distance plus_100
  <chr>         <chr>        <dbl>    <lgl>
1   123             A           70    FALSE
2   456             C          140     TRUE
3   789             D          140     TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! But seems like it summarises the entire `df`. Because I only get one row  which has 350 as `agg_distance`. `A          350     TRUE`.

Comment: Hm, when I use the code above with the `df` you provided in your question, I get exactly the output you wanted (as seen in my answer). Did you use it on different data? If so, how does the data differ from your example? Did you maybe forget to use `group_by`?

Comment: I do have my original data frame which is different from the example above, the example above is just an extraction of three columns out of more than 80 columns in the original data frame. But even though I try with this example `df` and with your code, I don't get the same result...

Comment: That is weird. Which version of `dplyr` / `tidyverse` do you use?

Comment: I updated dplyr and tidyverse but had the same problem. But thank you very much for your idea!